# DoS attack using iperf in the network

Tags: tcp, ddos, mininet, iperf

I would like to do a **TCP DoS** attack using iperf in my simulated network. (I use mininet). The only code that I could find is the following command for making UDP burst traffic in my network which is not relevant.

```
(host1: 10.0.0.1) iperf -s
(host2: 10.0.0.2) iperf -c 10.0.0.1 -b 30M -l 1200
```

Please let me know if there is a better code to do the **TCP DoS** attack using iperf or even if, there is any other code or approach to make TCP traffic as an attack.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's not much code here (one command). Consider posting to the Information Security StackExchange in the future. https://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I could do is that, just to add number of iperf tx form attacker using threads. In this way,it sends packet in parallel to the server. So, I used the following code:

```
host1: 10.0.0.1) iperf -s
(host2: 10.0.0.2) iperf -c 10.0.0.1 -b 30M -l 1200 -P 6
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send UDP flooding, then you must use `-u` switch on the server command:

```
iperf -s -u
```

on the client side, using your specification, it will be:

```
iperf -c 10.0.0.1 -t 200 -l 1200 -P 6
```

Answer (score 0):

iperf is suitable for bandwidth testing. If you want to do ddos attack, please try hping3 or dperf.

Comment: Why are these better tools?